# Add button to open dtale in new tab from plotly Dash

Tags: python, flask, plotly-dash

I'm trying to create a button that opens dtale where the data that is opened in dtale is dynamic and the button is from within a multi-page Dash app. The main set up is as follows where init_dashboard returns the Dash object. I'm currently unable to open dtale at all from within the Dash app.

```
def init_app(self):
    """Construct core Flask application with embedded Dash app."""
    app = build_app(reaper_on=False)

    @app.route('/')
    def homepage():
        return redirect('/dashboard')


    with app.app_context():
        app = self.init_dashboard(app)
        return app
```

Within the Dash app there is the callback below:

```
        @app.callback(
            Output('link_{}'.format(graph_title), 'children'),
            Input('button_{}'.format(graph_title), 'n_clicks')
        )
        def callback_func(n_clicks ):
            if n_clicks > 0 and n_clicks is not None:
                @app.server.route("/create-df")
                def create_df():
                    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1, 2, 3], b=[4, 5, 6]))
                    instance = startup(data=df, ignore_duplicate=True)
                    return redirect(f"/dtale/main/{instance._data_id}", code=302)
                return dcc.Link('Open dtale' , href = "create-df" , target = "_blank" ,  id = 'link_{}'.format(graph_title))

            else:
                return html.Div()
```

This links to :

```
div = html.Div(
            dbc.Card(
                dbc.CardBody([
                    dbc.Row([
                        html.Br(),
                        dbc.Col(dbc.Button("Export to dtale", id = 'button_{}'.format(graph_title) , n_clicks = 0 ,active = True , style = {'float' : 'right'})  , width = 12),
                        dbc.Col(html.Div("",   id = 'link_{}'.format(graph_title) ,  style = {'float' : 'right'})  , width = 12)
                    ] , align = 'center')
                ])
            )
        )
```

There is also a callback in the dashapp the link to a dcc.Location element, unsure if this is relevant to the problem

```
    @app.callback(Output('page-content', 'children'),
                  [Input('url', 'pathname')])
    def display_page(pathname):
        for page in self.graph_config['page']:
            tab_keys = list(self.dash_pages[page].keys())
            if pathname == '/' + page.lower():
                return self.dash_pages[page][tab_keys[0]]
            for tab in tab_keys:
                if pathname == '/' + page.lower() + '/' + tab.lower():
                    return self.dash_pages[page][tab]
        return self.dash_pages[page][tab_keys[0]]
```